# How to create checksum of the output of a select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, hash

I have 15 different systems (with 15 SQL databases). There is a customizing table which should have the same content everywhere. It contains less than 30 rows, so using

```sql
select * from table
```

is not heavy. I would like to compare the output of the table in the systems, but I don't want to compare row by row, cell by cell, I just need a hash (checksum) which will contain the stamp of each cell. Is that possible in T-SQL?

Comment: You can use CHECKSUM or BINARY_CHECKSUM functions but make sure to read the documentations to understand their limitations.  Here is a link for the doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: A short way is `BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)` per row, then aggregating these up with `CHECKSUM_AGG`. The drawback is that `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is a terrible checksum function with lots of potential for collisions (it is, however, very slightly less worse than `CHECKSUM`). More intricate approaches using `HASHBYTES` require cooking up some dynamic SQL to actually select columns by name, if you don't want to write them out.

Answer (score 0):

you can concat all columns then do checksum.
for example:

```
select binary_checksum(concat(col1,'|',col2,'|',col3,'|',col4)) from table
```

Instead of comparing long string you will compare checksum output.